# For muti-dimension flavors, how to disable certain combinations?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

My Android project has two flavor dimensions but some variants (certain dimension combinations) do not make sense and so I would like to disable/omit them.

Furthermore, for some variants I do not want both debug and release build types (one is enough because those variants are for internal use only).

How to achieve both of these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`variantFilter`](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Filtering-Variants) like below. Here, we want to disable the variant of a certain flavor combination for debug build type:

```
android {
    ...
    android.variantFilter { variant ->
        def name1 = variant.getFlavors().get(0).name
        def name2 = variant.getFlavors().get(1).name
        def isDebug = variant.buildType.name.equals('debug')
        if (name1.equals('ignoredName1') && name2.equals('ignoredName2') && isDebug)
            variant.setIgnore(true);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```